# When using Floyd's algorithm on a full circular linked list, the head becomes None

Tags: linked-list

I have a linked list. I am writing a function that returns `False` if there is no loop in my linked list and `True` if there is.

When I perform the algorithm, I need to have 2 pointers: one is `slow` and the other is `fast`.

Algorithm used:

- `slow` will move one step
- `fast` will move two steps
- if `slow==fast`, then loop exists
- and to break the loop :
- set `fast` at `head`, move `fast=fast.next` and `slow=slow.next` till `fast.next` is not equal to `slow.next`, and then set `slow.next` as `None`.

But in the following case my `head` becomes `None`. Can you help fixing this?

```py
def detectAndRemoveCycle(head):
    if head is None:
        return
    
    slow=head
    fast=head
    
    while slow and fast and fast.next:
        slow=slow.next
        fast=fast.next.next
        if slow==fast:
            fast=head
            while fast.next != slow.next:
                fast=fast.next
                slow=slow.next
            slow.next=None
            return True
            
 
    return False
```

Here is the case when my code fails, as it points my `head` to `None`

[image: the case when my code fails , as it points my head to Null]

Comment: Add some comments that show _why_ eventually slow and fast, and less trivial, _why_ the while loop ends. And what is the result that you want if the first element of the list is already part of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this algorithm will not always work when the linked list is circular, i.e. when the head node is part of the cycle.

There are several ways to resolve this. A simple solution is to create a temporary new head node that is prepended to the given head node. Then it will also work for this special case:

```py
def detectAndRemoveCycle(head):
    if head is None:
        return
    
    head = Node(None, head)    # <--- add this
    # ...rest of your code
```

This assumes your `Node` class is defined with a constructor that takes a second argument, like this:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = nxt
```

Comment: Could you give some feed-back to this answer?